# ANOVA syntax in RPy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, anova

First time using the RPy2 implementation in Python. Attempting to do an one-way ANOVA with two factors. It works in R on another machine, but Python does not like the syntax. Any thoughts are appreciated!

```
from rpy2.robjects import aov

huanova = aov(formula = df1['human_den'] ~ df1['region']+df1['years'])
```

Error message points at the tilda.

```
huanova = aov(formula=df1['human_den'] ~ df1['region']+df1['years'])
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @CactusWoman Added the error message. Just a simple SyntaxError

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tilde `~` is Unary in python, but you are using it as Binary. You may want:

```
 huanova = aov(formula = df1['human_den'] + ~ df1['region']+df1['years'])
```

Notice that I've added a PLUS before Tilde.

Comment: Not at all (! @ all ). The tilde in R is part of a formula's definition. It does not translate to Python's unary tilde. I downvoted because of that.

Comment: I dont know about tilde in R but here OP got a syntax error cause the tilde in Python is unary. There should be a way to use the R's tilde  but not that way

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation about Formulae in Rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/robjects_formulae.html), you have to pass the formula as a string. This is one way of doing it:

```
from rpy2.robjects import aov
from rpy2.robjects import Formula

formula = Formula('human_den ~ region + years')
env = formula.environment
env['human_den'] = df1['human_den']
env['region'] = df1['region']
env['years'] = df1['years']

huanova = aov(formula = formula)
```

Comment: `aov` is not in `robjects`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from [musically_ut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987185/musically-ut) will work but you need load the 'stats' package that contains the aov function using importr, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876274/running-rs-aov-mixed-effects-model-from-python-using-rpy2):

```
from rpy2.robjects import Formula 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')

formula = Formula('human_den ~ region + years')
env = formula.environment
env['human_den'] = df1['human_den']
env['region'] = df1['region']
env['years'] = df1['years']

huanova = stats.aov(formula = formula)
```